# Using NSPredicate with transformable attribute in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, transformable

I have A class (**TestClass**) and it has two Properties **ID : String** and **Code : Int**.

```
class TestClass : NSObject , NSCoding {

@objc let ID : Int32
@objc let Code : String

init(id : Int32, code : String) {

    self.ID = id
    self.Code = code
}

public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

    aCoder.encode(ID, forKey: "ID")
    aCoder.encode(Code, forKey: "Code")
}

required public convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    guard let id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "ID") as? Int32, let code = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Code") as? String else {

        return nil
    }
    self.init(id: id, code: code)
}}
```

I use this class for my **Transformable** Type.

```
@NSManaged public var trnsf: TestClass?
```

Every thing Looks so nice, even I can **sort** my fetch request based by **ID**

```
let SortDes = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(SomeEntity.trnsf.ID), ascending: true)//delete
```

The Problem:

I don't have access to NSPredicate for **Name** String

```
let Prdct = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@" ,#keyPath(SomeEntity.trnsf.Code) , "SomethingString")
```

please Attention that:

1. I know CoreData save my class as A Data and only I can use "%K == %@"
2. I know about **relations** in CoreData but I don't want to use it in this case
3. it's working like below but I want to compare Properties and not all class, because I don't know the id

   ```
   let Prdct = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@" , #keyPath(SomeEntity.trnsf.ID) , TestClass(id: 1, code: text))
   ```

Comment: You can't use the predicate in a fetch from a SQLite store. SQLite can't use your decoder.

Comment: Don't do that. Make an entity from `TestClass`