# Storing an UIView subclass or UIBezierPath in core data as transformable

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Is there a way to store an UIView subclass or UIBezierPath in core data?

What I have got so far:

1. I have already stored frame as transformable in Core Data by converting it to NSValue. However, when I tried to do: `myView as NSValue` I got error saying "can't convert to NSValue" even `myView` already conformed to `NSCoding`
2. I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223862/using-nspredicate-with-transformable-attribute-in-core-data)  and I think I'm probably missing ValueTransformer? I checked [documentation of ValueTransformer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/valuetransformer) out but I'm still confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Core Data Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Cocoa/CoreDataReleaseNotes/), you just have to set the attribute type to “transformable”. If you don't define a transformer, it uses `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName`, which is fine for you, because both `UIBezierPath` and `UIView` conform to `NSCoding`.